# Http Post returns 200 but is not working

Tags: android, http, post

First of all I must say I'm quite new in HTTP. I'm triying to submit a post request in my parents' restaurant website in order to register a new user from my app.

The website is this (in spanish): http://pedidos.pizzeriabritannia.com/index.asp?Opc=Registro

As far as I know the post request has these valuePairs:

```
 <form name="formulario" method="post" action="index.asp?Opc=Registro&Sub=Nuevo" >

 <input type="text" size="20" name="nombre" value="" style="background-color:#f5f7fe" />                              
 <input type="text" size="30" name="apellidos" value="" style="background-color:#f5f7fe" />
 <input type="text" size="30" name="direccion" value="" style="background-color:#f5f7fe" />
 <input type="text" size="20" name="nif" id="nif" style="background-color:#f5f7fe" value="" />
 <input type="text" size="30" name="email" id="email" value="" style="background-color:#f5f7fe"/>
 <input type="text" size="20" name="telefono" value=""  style="background-color:#f5f7fe" />
 <input type="text" size="10" name="clave" value="" style="background-color:#f5f7fe" />      
 <input type="checkbox" value="S" name="correo"  checked="checked"  />
```

And in my Android code I do:

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://pedidos.pizzeriabritannia.com/index.asp?Opc=Registrado");

StringBuilder data = null;
String answer ="";
    try {
        // Add your data
        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("nombre", Nombre));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("apellidos", Apellidos));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("calle", Calle));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("direccion", Detalles));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", Email));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("clave", contrasena));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("telefono", telefono));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("nif", ""));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("correo", "s"));

        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

        // Execute HTTP Post Request
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        data = inputStreamToString(response.getEntity().getContent());
        int code = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
        answer = code + data.toString();


    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    }
    return answer;

}
```

I'm getting 200 as response which means everything went fine but the problem is that an email should be sent to the email address provided in the form and this is not happening.
Do you have any idea? Any suggestion I could follow?

EDITTED:

```
private StringBuilder inputStreamToString(InputStream is) {
    String line = "";
    StringBuilder total = new StringBuilder();

    // Wrap a BufferedReader around the InputStream
    BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

    // Read response until the end
    try {
        while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) { 
            total.append(line); 
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    // Return full string
    return total;
}
```

Comment: didn't you need that `&Sub=Nuevo` part in your url ?

Comment: Do you think so? I'll try...

Comment: also, apparently on that particular post, 200 may not mean that everything is ok, as there seems to be some server-side validation. A 200 is returned, but the attached web page explains the error. I suggest you try to see what is the error message there. (you can display it in a webview, for example.)

Comment: I get the HTML of the attached web page in a string. If I scan that code, could I find the error?

Comment: display it in a webview, you'll see the error.

Comment: I can't see the error. I just see the webpage with the empty form.

Comment: are you sure you are displaying the content of data ?

Comment: Man! Solved it thanks to you! The problem was i was not adding the part you mentioned: &Sub=Nuevo. If you want you can post it as an answer and I'll accept it! Sorry for such an stupid question but as you can see i'm quite new.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The HTML extract mention the following address : `index.asp?Opc=Registro&Sub=Nuevo`

You are apparently making your request on `index.asp?Opc=Registrado`, which is different, as the `&Sub=Nuevo` part is missing. (The Nuevo value probably indicates the creation of a new item).

Answer (score 0):

```
 data = inputStreamToString(response.getEntity().getContent());
```

replace it with

```
  data = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
```

Comment: while this is technically true, it is not an answer, but rather a comment.